# How to pass case class as a variable into ScalaReflection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types

I am trying to pass a case class as a variable to ScalaReflection to get the schema.

I am able to run the code successfully with case class name where as when I assign the case class to a variable and pass that to ScalaReflection I am getting error.

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

case class Emp (empId: Integer, empName: String)
val myschema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Emp].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
println(myschema)

val empModel = Emp
val myschema2 = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[empModel].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

Error: error: not found: type empModel
val myschema2 = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[empModel].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Any suggestion is helpful!

Comment: Pass class not the object ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type synonyms (= aliases) should be introduced with a keyword `type`

```
type empModel = Emp
val myschema2 = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[empModel].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

In Scala values and types make different namespaces.

Top definitions with `type` (and `val`) are not allowed in Scala 2, so they have to be inside some object

```
object App {
  type empModel = Emp
  val myschema2 = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[empModel].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
}
```