# How to change datatype of columns in a dataframe based on a case class in scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying a convert data type of some columns based on a case class.

```
val simpleDf = Seq(("James",34,"2006-01-01","true","M",3000.60),
                     ("Michael",33,"1980-01-10","true","F",3300.80),
                     ("Robert",37,"1995-01-05","false","M",5000.50)
                 ).toDF("firstName","age","jobStartDate","isGraduated","gender","salary")

// Output
simpleDf.printSchema()
root
|-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
|-- age: integer (nullable = false)
|-- jobStartDate: string (nullable = true)
|-- isGraduated: string (nullable = true)
|-- gender: string (nullable = true)
|-- salary: double (nullable = false)
```

Here I wanted to change the datatype of `jobStartDate` to Timestamp and `isGraduated` to Boolean. I am wondering if that conversion is possible using the case class?
I am aware this can be done by casting each column but in my case, I need to map the incoming DF based on a case class defined.

```
case class empModel(firstName:String, 
                       age:Integer, 
                       jobStartDate:java.sql.Timestamp, 
                       isGraduated:Boolean, 
                       gender:String,
                       salary:Double
                      )

val newDf = simpleData.as[empModel].toDF
newDf.show(false)
```

I am getting errors because of the string to timestamp conversation. Is there any workaround?

Comment: in fact I receive those files from another application and all these columns are of string type. To change the column type in the DF, I need to manually operate on each DF and I have almost 50 data frame where I need to modify the some column data type. so wondering if that can be handled dynamically. Looking  at the scala reflection but not much help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass case class as a variable into ScalaReflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985339/how-to-pass-case-class-as-a-variable-into-scalareflection)

Comment: I checked the reflection but it is not the solution I am looking at. There is an answer posted that converts the datatype properly when I do the printSchema, but when i do df.show() then it throws exception.

Comment: For timestamp conversion, `newDf.withColumn("jobStartDate", to_timestamp($"jobStartDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))` works fine for me (on Spark 2.4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the schema from the case class using `ScalaReflection`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection


val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[empModel].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Now, you can pass this schema when you load your files into dataframe.

Or if you prefer to cast some or all columns after you read the dataframe, you can iterate the schema fields and cast into corresponding data type. By using `foldLeft` for example :

```
val df = schema.fields.foldLeft(simpleDf){ 
  (df, s) => df.withColumn(s.name, df(s.name).cast(s.dataType))     
}

df.printSchema

//root
// |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
// |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
// |-- jobStartDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
// |-- isGraduated: boolean (nullable = false)
// |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
// |-- salary: double (nullable = false)

df.show
//+---------+---+-------------------+-----------+------+------+
//|firstName|age|       jobStartDate|isGraduated|gender|salary|
//+---------+---+-------------------+-----------+------+------+
//|    James| 34|2006-01-01 00:00:00|       true|     M|3000.6|
//|  Michael| 33|1980-01-10 00:00:00|       true|     F|3300.8|
//|   Robert| 37|1995-01-05 00:00:00|      false|     M|5000.5|
//+---------+---+-------------------+-----------+------+------+
```